# MATLAB: Product of products with execution time in milliseconds

Tags: matlab, matrix, time

I have a code that actually works but the output is supposed to be multiplied together. Also, the time of execution was not in milliseconds. This is the Matlab code

```
function product = prod(A) 
tic; 
A=input('matrix A ='); 
[rows, columns] = size(A); 
for i=1:rows
prod=A(i,i)*A(i,end) 
end 
seconds=toc
```

For instance if given `A=[1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9]` when `i=1` we have `1*3=3` when `i=2` we have `2*6=12` when `i=3` we have `9*9=81`.
The output I want should be `3*12*81=2916` (the product of the values above) and the time of execution should be milliseconds.

When I extend the solution you proffer for the code below, it does not multiply them together and the time elapsed seems to be big

When the above code is used for the `matrix A = [2,3,6,4;2,1,7,-2;6,8,1,-3;5,3,4,1]`.

My output is

```
out = -22, -23, -7, -3
Elapsed time is 10.200446 seconds.
```

I want all the output to multiple each other so that it will be

```
out = -22*-23*-7*-3 = 10626
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. So what is the issue? What execution time do you get and why should it be in milliseconds? `prod=A(i,i)*A(i,end)` is overwritte in every iteration of your `for` loop. You rather need to initialize your loop with `prod = 1` and the have `prod=prod*A(i,i)*A(i,end)`. There may be an even more efficient way to perform your calculations. ;)

Comment: it seems that the second element should be 5*6, and not 2*6, am I correct?

Comment: Just as a word of warning, never create a function with the same name as a MATLAB built-in function. As long as this function `prod` is in your current path, [`prod`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/prod.html) will not work properly. Also, you are assigning the value of the multiplication to `prod` which then overwrites the function name. I assume you meant to assign the results to your return value `product`.

Comment: Also, you are calling `tic` **before** your call to `input`, so the time taken inputting your matrix is included in your timing. This is probably a bad thing. But the `input` should be unnecessary because you're passing `A` as a function parameter. If you call your function with the matrix you can completely remove the `input` line. There are other serious errors with your code, but I can't tell how to fix them unless you explain exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: 1) You're completely ignoring the code that @Ibezito gave you which would make the loops unnecessary. 2) You seem to now want to multiply the `end-1` column by the `end` row, but I'm not sure. 3) I don't understand why, if the number of rows is odd, you want to take only half of the matrix.

Comment: Well, you still haven't explained exactly what you're trying to accomplish. I could make assumptions, but I'd rather not write an answer and have to keep modifying it to solve the real problem.

Comment: And how do you get "all of the values computed from the code"? What rows/columns/diagonals are you trying to multiply together to get those values? I'm trying to get you to tell me what the general formula is that you're trying to implement instead of giving me an example of what this code does in this particular instance. It would also be helpful if you pinged me if you want a response using @beaker. It'll save me having to check back to see if you've made any updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it took me some time to decipher what you have been trying to do, but finally, I was able to reconstruct your output. So first, there is no need for the `prod` function, it only makes things messy.
Here is a simple function that does the trick:

```
function out = testValue
A=input('matrix A =');
out=1;
if mod(size(A),2)==0
    for i = 1:length(A)
        out = out*(A(i,i)*A(i,end)-A(i,end-1)*A(end,i));
    end
else
    for i = 1:(length(A)-1)/2
        out = out*(A(i,i)*A(i,end)-A(i,end-1)*A(end,i));
    end
end
end
```

Some remarks on the code above:

1. No need for the `columns` variable
2. I omitted the `tic` `toc` - you can add them back if needed
3. No use for the `prod` function, instead the input for `prod` is simply what you consider as its output.
4. You **have** to initialize `out=1` for a cumulative product

I'm sure there are cleverer ways to do this, but as @beaker wrote it is not clear what exactly is the purpose of this code.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am sorry for packing all the questions at once for solution. First, help me edit the code so that it is executable @EBH

Comment: This is becoming too messy, why you don't start a different question?

Comment: @babs Please ask new questions in a new post. To mark an answer as the correct one, click on the green check mark to the left of the answer. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers